# Postgres+JDBC Template too many clients already exception

Tags: java, postgresql, rest, jdbctemplate

I am using postgresql but i am getting this exception `FATAL: sorry, too many clients` already while fetching records from the table in the database.

Fallowing is the connection class:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.trinity" />
      <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:/jdbc.properties" order="1" ignore-unresolvable="true"/>   
      <beans:bean id="dataSourcePOSTGRESQL" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">  
        <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="${pg_jdbc.driverClassName}" />
        <beans:property name="url" value="${pg_jdbc.url}" />
        <beans:property name="username" value="${pg_jdbc.username}" />
        <beans:property name="password" value="${pg_jdbc.password}" /> 
    </beans:bean>
```

jdbc.propertis

```
pg_jdbc.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
pg_jdbc1.url1=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5433/iotdb
pg_jdbc.username=postgres
pg_jdbc.password=track@123
```

Dao class:

```
public List<Map<String, Object>> getAllDevicesNames(Integer companyId) {

    String sql = "select device_configuration_id,device_name,device_id from iot.device_configuration where company_id = ? ";
    List<Map<String, Object>> queryForList = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(sql,new Object[]{companyId});
    return queryForList;

}
```

Comment: Are you using a connection pool? Do you have any idea how many open connections you have?

Comment: Most likely, you aren't closing your connections, but without seeing your connection code(s) we cannot say for certain.

Comment: (As a side note, you can skip the configuration if you use Spring Boot. It'll even automatically configure a connection pool and JDBC template for you.)

Comment: No i am not closing any connection , i am using connection pooling that closing all connection is taken care by jdbc template only right?

Comment: <beans:bean id="jdbcTemplatePOSTGRESQL" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">  
 <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourcePOSTGRESQL"></beans:property>  
 </beans:bean>

Answer (score 1):

Previously in my postgres.cfg file

```
max_connections = 100
shared_buffers = 128kb
```

Now, i changed to the

```
max_connections = 300
shared_buffers = 80MB
```

It is working fine.

Comment: If it is working as expected plz accept the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this query to find the number of connections:

```
SELECT sum(numbackends) FROM pg_stat_database;
```

The standard 100 max database connections server can have with the database server may not be enough for production use. To increase this Postgres default in a Linux setup, you can follow these steps:

in

```
/var/lib/pgsql/data/postgresql.conf
```

you would find these 2 settings
at 100, 24 MB respectively. You can change them to the following:

```
max_connections = 300
shared_buffers = 80MB
```

Comment: If he has that many connections in a dev environment, then he's almost certainly leaking them somewhere.